# Transfer data to List and keep the same length from file

Tags: python

I am trying to read data from `.txt` file and save them into the `list` and keep the data structure.

Example `.txt` file:

```
   num value1 value2
     1  0.1     0.2
     2  0.3         
     3          0.4
```

then what I want is to generate the List `[['num','value1','value2'],[1,0.1,0.2],[2,0.3,' '],[3,' ',0.4]]`

Here's my code:

```
L=[]

with open('txtfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        L.append(line.split())
        print(L)
```

- The result is `[['num', 'value1', 'value2'], ['1', '0.1', '0.2'], ['2', '0.3'], ['3', '0.4']]` not as expected
- How to fix my code th get the correct result as `[['num','value1','value2'],[1,0.1,0.2],[2,0.3,' '],[3,'',0.4]]????`

Comment: It could be done. But the `.txt` file need to have better formatting. Are the values separated by `\t`? Or only spaces, and how many spaces?

Comment: Consider correcting this at the data source if possible: tab-separated or comma-separated file would be best.

Comment: @JakubSzlaur the values separated by spaces,and is there any way to sperated the values and remain the blank value into List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a horribly formatted file to read, and I'd personally request a new one for parsing with either tabs as Jakub said or comma-seperated (csv).

That said, they are spaced with tabs, so you'll just have to split each line manually. The `split()` function will consume all whitespaces between words.

```
for line in f.readlines():
    line_number = line[0:3].strip()
    first_element = line[3:11].strip()
    second_element = line[11:].strip()
    L.append([line_number, first_element, second_element])
print(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflict with the `split()` function. Your method to list the data is by detecting and "overwriting" spaces, but you also overwrite the empty values.

You can start by marking empty values. Empty value can be `empty`, `$`, or anything else. When parsing the data, handle them.

When you feel confident enough with python, and programming in general, consider using `.json` files, and working with `pandas` or other similar libraries.

Answer (score -1):

if you separate columns in txt file with comma you can use pandas to get the list

```
num, value1, value2
 1  ,0.1     ,0.2
 2  ,0.3,         
 3  ,   ,     0.4

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt")
df.values.tolist()
```

Comment: if you were to add commas, you could just split on the commas